# Python Bottle template engine does not allow period

Tags: python, bottle

It looks like the Bottle template engine does not periods in it's template variables. The following code:

```
from bottle import template
x = 'blah {{blah.blah}} blah'
d = {'blah.blah': 'doodah'}
template(x, **d)
```

Gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "E:\WPy-3662\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3622, in template
    return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)
  File "E:\WPy-3662\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3411, in render
    self.execute(stdout, env)
  File "E:\WPy-3662\python-3.6.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\bottle.py", line 3398, in execute
    eval(self.co, env)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'blah' is not defined
```

I need periods. I'm keeping my templates in a multi-line string array and then passing an array of dictionaries to the Bottle template engine.

How can I get around this?

Comment: Does it let you do something like `x = 'blah {{blee}} blah'` then `template(x, blee=blah.blah)`?

Comment: Yes it allows me to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is not with Bottle, but in how python parses the variables during eval.

The template string `blah.blah` When run through eval creates a variable name blah.blah, which turns into a two part notation.

```
blah.blah = 'doodah'
```

can't work.  Though it does work in a dictionary since it is a string name. If you replace the dot with an underline, it will work, because an underline is a valid variable name.

Comment: Are there any template engines in Python where it will work?

Comment: No.  Because it's not a template problem.  dot notation is understood by python as an operator, in this case looking for a class.  If you separated by an underscore, you will notice it works. Now if you are bringing in a class of blah, then this will work.